# How to submit/run multiple parallel jobs with Slurm/Sbatch?

Tags: python, shell, slurm, sbatch

I am trying to submit a large number of jobs (several hundred) to a Slurm server and was hoping to avoid having to submit a new shell script for each job I wanted to run. The code submitted is a Python script that takes two input variables in the shell script and those variables are the only thing that changes between jobs. An example of a short shell script that works for a single job is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -t 01:00:00

srun python retrieve.py --start=0 --end=10
```

What I want is to submit a large number of jobs with the same python script and only change the 'start' and 'end' variables between jobs. I read something about just increasing the number of cores needed ('-n') and writing an & symbol after each srun-command, but I've been unable to get it to work so far.

If anyone knows a quick way to do this, I would appreciate the help a lot!

Comment: Like this? `for ((i=0; i<=100; i+=10)); do srun python retrieve.py --start="$i" --end="$((i+10))" & done`

Answer (score 9):

To build up from your current solution, you can move to using two CPUs rather than one with:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -n 2
#SBATCH -t 01:00:00

srun -n1 --exclusive python retrieve.py --start=0 --end=10 &
srun -n1 --exclusive python retrieve.py --start=10 --end=20 &
wait
```

(you might need to adapt the `--end` based on whether the bounds are inclusive or exclusive)

The above script requests 2 CPUs and creates two tasks running the Python script with the different arguments. The `--exclusive` part is necessary for Slurm versions prior to 20.11 (from memory). It has nothing to do with the eponym option of `sbatch` that requests wholes nodes.

The ampersand (`&`) allows both tasks to run in parallel and the `wait` command is there to make sure the script does not terminate before the tasks, otherwise Slurm will just kill them.

You can generalise with a Bash `for`-loop or using the [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) command.

This however will not submit multiple jobs, it will submit one job with multiple tasks.

If you want to submit multiple jobs, you will need a [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -t 01:00:00
#SBATCH --array=0-10:10

srun python retrieve.py --start=${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} --end=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID+10))
```

This will submit two independent jobs that will perform the same work as the job described before.